# Query if a field is greaterThan another field.

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I didn't have any idea how to word this question, but basically I have a document with the following table structure:

```
-- objectId, lastCheckedDate, lastMaintainedDate, totalChecks --
```

I want to write a parse query that looks like this:

```
let query = PFQuery(class: MyClass.getParseClassName())
query.whereKey("lastCheckedDate", greaterThan: "lastMaintainedDate")
```

unfortunately,t he above does not work, so I was hoping someone could lend me a hand.

Answer (score 0):

When you provide an object to run against the "greaterThan" query constraint, you can't provide another column name. The code you provided is checking if the string "lastMaintainedDate" is greater than the data in the lastCheckedDate column.

One solution would be to run the query without the "greaterThan" constraint. Then when you run the query, with:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
   if error == nil {
       //your code here
   }
}
```

Add code to the "your code here" section to check where the result from the current result in the lastMaintainedDate column is greater than the result in the lastCheckedDate column. This solution may use a little more data than you want, but this is the most efficient way I know to do this.

More information on queries can be found [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries)